# POST into Table through OData

Tags: javascript, post, odata, sapui5

Is it possible to POST into 1 Table from a Collection, delivered through OData?

Here is my Scenario:
I am using the following:

```
service{
 "APPAPP"."CHANGE_REQUESTS" 
                        as "CHANGE_REQUEST_LIST" navigates ("ID_OBJ" as "OBJECT");
 "APPAPP"."CHANGE_REQUESTS_DETAIL"
                         as "INFO_LIST";

 association "ID_OBJ"
 principal "CHANGE_REQUEST_LIST"("ID_OBJ")
 multiplicity "1"
 dependent "INFO_LIST"("CHR_ID")
 multiplicity "*";
 }
```

to deliver 2 Joined Tables with a OData Connection, to a SAPUI5 Fiori App.
Now I am trying to POST data back into my Database, although when I try to address only one of the tables (containing 20 entries) through the URL, I get the following error:

> The segment '$metadata' at position 20 in the request URI is not valid. Since the previous segment refers to a collection, the only supported value for the next segment is '$count'.

**Question:** is it possible for me to do this, using the existing connection? Are there any hints you could give me, or is it strictly impossible to POST on only one Table using this connection?

Comment: you need to POST into an EntitySet, not into a metadata-URL ... where do you post to?

Answer (score 0):

got it.

```
    oModel.create("/CHANGE_REQUEST_LIST", {
    ID_OBJ: 10,
    NAME: "CHR1" 
}, {
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {...},
    error: function(response) {...}
});
```